# how to give index of clustered array python?

Tags: python, indexing, cluster-analysis

i've try to run this K-Medoids python implementation  code

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances
import numpy as np

import kmedoids

# 3 points in dataset
data = np.array([[1,1], 
                [2,2], 
                [10,10]])

# distance matrix
D = pairwise_distances(data, metric='euclidean')

# split into 2 clusters
M, C = kmedoids.kMedoids(D, 2)

print('medoids:')
for point_idx in M:
    print( data[point_idx] )

print('')
print('clustering result:')
for label in C:
    for point_idx in C[label]:
        print('label {0}:　{1}'.format(label, data[point_idx]))
```

(https://github.com/someus/kmedoids) and it shows:

> medoids:
>
> [1 1]
>
> [10 10]
>
> clustering result:
>
> label 0:　[1 1]
>
> label 0:　[2 2]
>
> label 1:　[10 10]

But i wanna insert index on its clustering result like this:

> medoids:
>
> [1 1], index 1
>
> [10 10], index 3
>
> clustering result:
>
> label 0:　[1 1], index 1
>
> label 0:　[2 2], index 2
>
> label 1:　[10 10], index 3

Does anyone knows how to make it?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean you want to print `point_idx`, too?

```
print('label {0}:　{1} {2}'.format(label, data[point_idx], point_idx))
```